# Creating dynamic query using jpa criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I created dynamic query using jpa criteria but an extra pair of parentheses gets added to columns to be selected when I do userGroupSubquery.select(userGroupsRoot);

generated query

select (securitygr3_.group_name, securitygr3_.user_name) from gm.security_groupings securitygr3_ where 1=1 and securitygr3_.user_name='xxx' and (securitygr3_.group_name in ('XYZ'))

expected query:

select securitygr3_.group_name, securitygr3_.user_name from gm.security_groupings securitygr3_ where 1=1 and securitygr3_.user_name='xxx' and (securitygr3_.group_name in ('XYZ'))

```
Subquery<SecurityGroupings> userGroupSubquery = secUsersQuery.subquery(SecurityGroupings.class);
            Root<SecurityGroupings> userGroupsRoot = userGroupSubquery.from(SecurityGroupings.class);
            Path<SecurityGroupingsId> secGroupId = userGroupsRoot.get("id");
            Path<SecurityUsers> secUsers = secGroupId.get("securityUsers_1");
            Path<SecurityUsers> securityUsers = secGroupId.get("securityUsers");
            Path<String> su_name = secUsers.get("name");
            Path<String> name = securityUsers.get("name");
            userGroupSubquery.select(userGroupsRoot);
            userGroupSubquery.getCompoundSelectionItems();



//userGroupSubquery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(pet.get(SecurityGroupingsId_.id), root.<String>get("name")));
            Predicate restrictions3 = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
            restrictions3 = criteriaBuilder.and(restrictions3, criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(su_name, dto.getUserId().trim().toUpperCase())));
            restrictions3 = criteriaBuilder.and(restrictions3, criteriaBuilder.and(name.in(userGroups)));
            userGroupSubquery.where(restrictions3);
            restrictions = criteriaBuilder.and(restrictions, criteriaBuilder.exists(userGroupSubquery));
        }
        secUsersQuery.where(restrictions);
```

Its just that I get an extra pair of parentheses at select (securitygr3_.group_name, securitygr3_.user_name) from 
which gives me ora-00907 missing right parenthesis error. I am sure it is coming from userGroupSubquery.select(userGroupsRoot) but I am not sure why. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for the above. When the entity has a composite key, then in JPA criteria instead of doing

```
userGroupSubquery.select(userGroupsRoot);
```

we should do

```
userGroupSubquery.select(userGroupsRoot.get("id"));
```

where id is the composite id.